# Does spring data solr support json.facet?

Tags: solr, spring-data-solr

Can I write the facet query like this in spring-data-solr?

```
json.facet={
    "topic_aggr":{
        "type": "terms",
        "field": "topic_ss",
        "limit": 10,
        "numBuckets": true,
        "allBuckets": true,
        "facet": {
            "updateTime":"max(createTime_dt)"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not mentioned at all in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/#solr.misc.faceting), only vanilla and Pivot faceting, so I would say: clearly not.